# Amazon Lex - Taking user input and storing it

Tags: amazon-lex

Is there a way to store the users input from slots? For example, the persons favourite meat is beef and bun is brioche. Then can this data be checked and returned with I recommend the Tennessee Stack that has a 6oz beef patty inside of a brioche bun.

Also, would it be possible to then have this data sent in an email automatically? Or am I asking too much?

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way! With this question, the best I can do is say "Yes" and point you in the right direction. If you have further questions, try to ask one at a time and make them specific enough that they can be given a direct answer that could be helpful to others with the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible, but not with Lex alone.

You'll have to use another Amazon Web Service or your own website/server to do the emailing and storing long-term. However, storing the input short-term (the length of the chat session) is what the slots already do.

To return a dynamic reply based on the data in the slots, you will have to handle the Lex input that is sent to a [Lambda Function](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/), and build your Lex Response there.

Here are the documentations that should help:
[Create a Lambda Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gs2-prepare.html)
[Handling Lex Inputs in your Lambda Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html)

There is also a video tutorial on walking you through setting up the Lex bot with Lambda and testing it out: [Intro to Lex - Bot Setup With Lambda](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jg_SsZGYmr0)